# Can @Query value contain multiple queries?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

For example; something like this:

```
@Modifying

@Nullable

@Query(value="INSERT INTO user (name, password) VALUES (:name, :password); SELECT last_insert_id();", nativeQuery=true)

Long insertUser(@Nullable @Param("name") String name, @Nullable @Param("password") String Password);
```

I tried to find an answer online but being a total novice at coding makes it difficult to recognize the answer even if found, so I turned to the pros.

Comment: No, only a single query. But why would you need this? Just insert the `User` entity and it will get an id assigned automatically. Looks like you are trying to work around JPA.

Comment: Thanks for answering!
The only reason I'm trying to do it this way is because my "user" isn't really an Entity, it represents several different table columns (it contains role_name, organization_name, job_name...etc.) so I was hoping to find a solution which wouldn't depend on stored procedures.
Again, thank you for the straight and fast answer.

Comment: If it isn't an entity then why are you using Spring Data JPA or JPA in general? Also why wouldn't it be an entity, the point of an entity is that it does represent several table columns, what else would it be?

Comment: I really don't know, I'm quite new at this. I just wanted to have the ID returned right after a successful insertion as part of a single call, just like in a stored procedure, instead of calling the database once again after. And I think I understand now what you were saying before - one table should be represented as one object(Entity) and what I was doing was putting columns from several different tables into one object. 
Thanks for clearing things up!

Comment: You can return the id depending on your database and the fact it supports `RETURNING` in SQL. However you are using JPA, so you reallly should be using that, or else you are using the wrong tool for the job and JPA might be a bad choice in the first place.